# 2007 - Excel 2010 not saving document to document library

Tags: document-library, 2007, excel

I've a document library with default document template on my SharePoint 2007 website.

When a new document is created, Excel is opened and then, when saving, it should prompt the SP document library as position where save the file.

It works fine on about 10 PCs, except one where Excel 2010 prompt to save to the local document folder.

I've tried to clean IE cache, checked compatibility mode, checked if the site is in trusted list, checked if Web Client service on SP server is enabled and running. But nothing helped.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Because it works on other PCs, so the issue is not related to `WebClient` service, and maybe related to the Excel option.

**So try to**

> Open Excel > Excel Options > Save > below Offline Editing > check the
>   web server

For more details, check [CAN NOT SAVE A DOCUMENT BACK INTO DOCUMENT LIBRARY IN SHAREPOINT](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/01/31/can-not-save-document-back-into-document-library-in-sharepoint-2010/)